# Java socket server with VB.NET client?

Tags: java, windows, vb.net, macos, sockets

Is this even possible? I have a java server program on a mac that I need to use to communicate back to a windows program. I have the client working in Java, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work in VB.net...

Here is the Java code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socketClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * Define a host server
     */
    String host = "10.1.1.194";
    /**
     * Define a port
     */
    int port = 19999;

    StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
    String TimeStamp;
    System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");

    try {

         //Obtain an address object of the server
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);


        //Establish a socket connection
        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);

        //Instantiate a BufferedOutputStream object  
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        /**
         * Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional
         * character encoding.
         */
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

        TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
        String process = "Initiate file transfer on " + host + " port " + port
                + " at " + TimeStamp + (char) 13;

        //Write across the socket connection and flush the buffer
        osw.write(process);
        osw.flush();


        /**
         * Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading /**
         * Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading incoming
         * socket streams.
         */
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        /**
         * Instantiate an InputStreamReader with the optional character
         * encoding.
         */
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");


        //Read the socket's InputStream and append to a StringBuffer
        int c;
        while ((c = isr.read()) != 13) {
            instr.append((char) c);
        }

        //Close the socket connection.
        connection.close();
        System.out.println(instr);
    } 
    catch (IOException f) 
    {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + f);
    } 
    catch (Exception g) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + g);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my VB.NET code that I have so far...

```
Private clientSocket As Socket
Private host As String = "10.1.1.194"
Private port As Integer = 19999

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try


        Dim add As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port)

        clientSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

        clientSocket.Connect(add)

        Dim netStream As New NetworkStream(clientSocket, True)



        Dim outstream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Initiate file transfer from " _
        & System.Environment.MachineName & " on " & host & " port " & port & " at " & TimeOfDay)


        netStream.Write(outstream, 0, outstream.Length)
        netStream.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try


    End Sub
```

Now, if I run the vb code, it hangs... and nothing appears in my console on the mac (Like it does when I use the java client), however, when I close the VB code, I get the java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error, so I must be getting pretty close to figuring this out.

The thing is, I know almost nothing when it comes to socket programming, so if someone could push me in the right direction, it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Yes.

I don't see you writing Carriage Return (13) character anywhere in your VB.NET example, yet you expect it to appear on a Java side in order to print something to the console.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Didn't even see that. Working perfectly, thanks!